# Secure way to access encryption keys and credential data in nodejs environment?

Tags: node.js, security, encryption, keystore

I am running nodejs apps access resources on different servers, and I need to store the keys somewhere. Now, it is considered a bad idea to check-in user credentials or encryption keys in code repository. What is the best way to manage these keys in a secure manner?

One option I found is to save them in environment variables, and then later read their value when needed in script. Two methods I know of to populate env variables are: set them while running the script on command line (e.g `USER_KEY=12345 node script.js`) or let them be read from a local file on hard drive. But I want to access these keys on a random CI pipeline machine, so cant store file on disk and cant load them from command line.

Second option is to read these keys from a remote machine. Is there a known Crypto/Key Management Service or another popular NodeJS way to save credentials in a key store and then let script read it from there at run-time. Is there another way?

Comment: The key question for you is: "Who do you want to protect your credentials from internally"?  Then, you have to find an appropriate place to store them that provides that level of security, yet still allows you to design some sort of deployment strategy to get the credentials from the store to the server that needs them.  For example, if you don't want all your developers to have access to them, then you can't store them in your source control system.

Comment: In companies I've been in, it was a few security specialists in operations who controlled the production security credentials and they were responsible for deploying them to production servers.  The rest of the company did not have access to them.